# Floating point format: why must `1−emax ≤ q+p−1 ≤ emax`?

Tags: floating-point, number-formats

From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats) on the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic,

> The possible finite values that can be represented in a format are determined by the base (b), the number of digits in the significand (precision, p), and the exponent (`q`) parameter `emax`:
>
> ...
>
> q must be an integer such that `1−emax ≤ q+p−1 ≤ emax` (e.g., if p=7 and emax=96 then q is −101 through 90).

I can't figure out the reasoning behind the above inequality. I would've thought (in my simplicity) that it would be `-emax ≤ q ≤ emax` or something similar. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The reason we get a larger range is *denormalized numbers*. Generally speaking, floating point numbers have three physical parts: sign (1 bit), mantissa $M$ and exponent $e$. Most of the time we think of the number as $\operatorname{sgn} \times 1.M \times 2^{e-e_0}$, where $e_0 = 2^{|e|}-1$ (e.g. for single precision, it's 127, since the exponent is allotted seven bits). Here "$1.M$" means the number you obtain by writing $M$ as a binary string and prefixing $1.$.

For reasons having to do with underflow (non-zero numbers turning to zero), it is important to be able to store numbers very close to zero. These numbers, named *denormalized numbers* or *subnormalized numbers*, have $e = 0$ and represent $\operatorname{sgn} \times 0.M \times 2^{1-e_0}$. (This means that *normal numbers* cannot have $e = 0$.) This explains the extended range mentioned in the Wikipedia page.

Other numbers having special encodings are $\pm \infty$ and NaN (not a number), which represent some illegal operation (division by zero, taking the logarithm of a non-positive number, taking the square root of a negative number, and so on). For more details, consult the Wikipedia page regarding the [original standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).

Comment: The exponent is allotted eight* bits IMO .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'subnormality' is at play here. However, 'normality' is!

The Wiki-page you refer to represents a number *x* to be
    
*x = c . b<sup>q</sup>* with *c = 0 ... b<sup>p</sup>-1*    (1)
However, the number we would want to store as an IEEE754 floating point number is represented differently:
    
*x = c' . b<sup>q'</sup>* with *c' = 0 ... 1-b<sup>-p</sup>*    (2)
This is the 'normalization' I referred to earlier.

We can relate (1) and (2) by reforming (1):
    
*x = c . b<sup>q</sup> = c . b<sup>-p+1</sup> . b<sup>p-1</sup> . b<sup>q</sup> = c' . b<sup>p-1</sup> . b<sup>q</sup> = c' . b<sup>q+p-1</sup>*

Therefore:
    
*q' = q+p-1*      (3)

We want to store *q'* using a limited number range. According to the IEEE 754 standard, we'll do this using 'bias'. Let's define the bias to be *e<sub>max</sub> - 1* (with *e<sub>max</sub>* being half the number range we have available. E.g., in the binary32 case we have 8 bits available in the exponent of a float. This leads to an *e<sub>max</sub> = 0.5 . 2<sup>8</sup> = 128*).
In view of this, we can write:
    
*-e<sub>max</sub>+1 ≤ q' ≤ e<sub>max</sub>*    (4)
This ensures that *q'* plus the bias fully covers the available (but limited) range.

Combining (3) and (4) yields the (at first sight) not so obvious equation of the wiki-page:
    
*-e<sub>max</sub>+1 ≤ q+p-1 ≤ e<sub>max</sub>*

I hope this helps!

Note: the true IEEE754 binary case also assumes the 'silent leading bit 1' which further complicates the matter and is indeed the root of subnormal numbers.

Comment: Welcome! For future reference, you can use LaTeX to typeset mathematics, which is a good deal easier that coding up all that HTML!  We have a [short reference](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) that explains the feature.